# Combining a Pre-trained Model with a Custom Model in TF

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have simple network that I would like to increase its complexity by combining it with a pre-trained model such as InceptionV3. However, once I join them together with the following command:

```
snn_model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=model, name = 'snn')
```

I face this error:

```
ValueError: Output tensors of a Functional model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional object at 0x7f82d1804c10>
```

My Network is as follows:

```
def build_siamese_model(inputShape, embeddingDim=48):

  # increase model complexity by adding Inception
  # make the network itself generate the embediings

  # specify the inputs for the feature extractor network
  inputs = Input(inputShape)

  # define the first set of CONV => RELU => POOL => DROPOUT layers
  x = Conv2D(64,(2,2), padding='same', activation='relu')(inputs)
  x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
  x = Dropout(0.3)(x)

  # second set of CONV => RELU => POOL => DROPOUT layers
  x = Conv2D(64,(2,2), padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
  x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
  x = Dropout(0.3)(x)

  # prepare the final outputs
  pooledOutput = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
  outputs = Dense(embeddingDim)(pooledOutput)

  # build the model
  model = Model(inputs, outputs)

  # return the model to the calling function
  return model
```

I am combining my network with InceptionV3 as follows:

```
baseModel = InceptionV3(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=(160, 160,3), input_tensor=Input(shape=(160, 160,3)))

snn_model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=model, name = 'snn')
```

Even if I try to switch between these models by giving the InceptionV3 output as an input to my custom network I got another error:

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node max_pooling2d_62/MaxPool}} = MaxPool[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", explicit_paddings=[], ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1]](Placeholder)' with input shapes: [?,1,1,64].
```

So, my idea is to combine a custom model with a pre-trained model to increase complexity and achieve a better performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple google search for transfer learning will have [Transfer learning and fine-tuning](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning) as the first result. I suggest that you read it first as it has exactly what you are trying to do.

Basically you will use `InceptionV3` as you would do a normal layer inside your `build_siamese_model` function that returns your entire model. Something like this will do:

```
# specify the inputs for the feature extractor network
inputs = Input(inputShape)

# define the first set of CONV => RELU => POOL => DROPOUT layers
x = baseModel(inputs) # initialized from InceptionV3
x = Conv2D(64,(2,2), padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
# the rest of your code ...
```

Again, you should read the documentation to understand how to properly instantiate a pre-trained model and handle batch normalization layers

Answer (score 0):

The first error is due to specifying output incorrectly. You should define output of the model, a output of a layer. So in order to resolve the first error, modified code, should be like this:

```
snn_model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=model.output, name = 'snn')
```

---

The second error, indicates, you are shrinking input tensor, through your model layers, until it reaches to `(1,1)` size. Then it can not go further, since each `Conv2D` or `MaxPooling` layer could makes the input size smaller, and it will gets negative, somewhere in your middle layers. So, try to remove some layers or architecture, or try to feed a bigger input size to avoid reaching a `(1,1)` tensor in middle layers. You can use `model.summary()` to see each layers output shape, in order to figure out the journey of input tensor throughout your layers.